Populate the dictionary [DateComponents: EventType], How to add dates to a date dictionary
I would like to get this result:
var eventDate: [DateComponents: EventType] = [
        DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: 2024, month: 7, day: 04): .busy,
        DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: 2024, month: 8, day: 07): .busy,
        DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: 2024, month: 10, day: 16): .busy,
        DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: 2024, month: 12, day: 17): .busy,
        DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: 2025, month: 4, day: 18): .busy,
        DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: 2026, month: 9, day: 26): .busy
    ]

I'm trying this way but I'm not getting what I want. I don't get the list you see at the beginning.
func dateTimestampDividedInt(date: TimeInterval) -> (year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)
            
            let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
            let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
            let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
            
            return (year, month, day)
        }

for employee in eventArrayIcon {
           
            let timeIntervalDateEndDivided = employee.dateEnd?.dateTimestampDividedInt(date: employee.dateEnd ?? 0.0)

                    let yearInt = timeIntervalDateEndDivided?.year
                    let monthInt = timeIntervalDateEndDivided?.month
                    let dayInt = timeIntervalDateEndDivided?.day
            
            eventDate = [
                DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: yearInt, month: monthInt, day: dayInt): .busy
            ]
            
        }


eventDate = [...] you are setting the value of eventDate. You mean to add objects for key each time: eventDate[DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: yearInt, month: monthInt, day: dayInt)] = .busy

You don’t have to create a new account when you ask a new question

can anyone help me?

Larme has given you the solution

I did this but xCode gives me an error: eventDate.append(DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: yearInt, month: monthInt, day: dayInt): .busy)

I also did as suggested by Larme but he only adds one, but I need many objects, i as wrote at the beginning.    [calendar: gregorian (gregorian) locale:  time zone: Europe firstWeekday: 1 minDaysInFirstWeek: 1 year: 2024 month: 7 day: 19 : .busy]

Stop what you're doing, open a Playground, and let's just do var myDic1: [String: Any] = [:]; for i in 0...20 { myDic1["Key\(i)"] = "Value \(i)"; print("Partial1: \(myDic1)") } print("Final1: \(myDic1)"); var myDic2: [String: Any] = [:]; for i in 0...20 { myDic2 = ["Key\(i)": "Value \(i)"]; print("Partial2: \(myDic2)") } print("Final2: \(myDic2)");. The code shown in your question is myDic2. The logic you want is myDic1. You are missing the logic on how to add new values to an existing Dictionary and mixing it with setting the value of a dictionary.

Now the other issue is that in a Dictionary keys are unic. So if DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: yearInt, month: monthInt, day: dayInt) is the same for each employee, it won't work.

Let's simplify and focus on how works the Dictionary as all the DateComponents make things noisy.
You can stop what you're doing, open a Playground and test to ensure your understanding of Dictionary is up to date and correct.
What you're currently doing: Setting the whole value of myDic1 each time
ie: Forget about your previous values, now you're just ["Key\(i)": "Value \(i)"]
So its output will be the last override ie myDic1 = ["Key\(4)": "Value \(4)"]
var myDic1: [String: Any] = [:]
for i in 0...4 {
    myDic1 = ["Key\(i)": "Value \(i)"]
    print("Partial1: \(myDic1)")
}
print("Final1: \(myDic1)")

What you want is to set the value for each new key:
var myDic2: [String: Any] = [:]
for i in 0...4 {
    myDic2["Key\(i)"] = "Value \(i)"
    print("Partial1: \(myDic2)")
}
print("Final2: \(myDic2)")

But for Dictionaries, key are unique. Meaning that if you do:
myDict[key] = Value0
myDict[key] = Value1

Then, myDict[key] will be Value1 (ie, the last one set for key.
var myDic3: [String: Any] = [:]
for i in 0...4 {
    myDic3["Key\(i)"] = "Value \(i)"
    print("Partial3: \(myDic3)")
}
for i in 0...4 {
    myDic3["Key\(i)"] = "New Value \(i)"
    print("Partial3: \(myDic3)")
}
print("Final3: \(myDic3)")

So in your case, if the key DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: yearInt, month: monthInt, day: dayInt) is the same for different employee, you'll get only the last value set. So you need to change your model.
I don't know what you want to do with your model, but var eventDate: [DateComponents: [EventType]] could be a solution, meaning that you can have multiple EventType for a same DateComponents, etc.
So you need to debug and print print("Partial1: \(myDic1)") equivalent in your code inside the loop.

Thanks Larme for the time you dedicated to me, I solved it with a for-in.      for eventCal in eventArrayIcon {
        let timeIntervalDateEndDivided = eventCal.dateEnd?.dateTimestampDividedInt(date: eventCal.dateEnd ?? 0.0)
        let yearInt = timeIntervalDateEndDivided?.year
        let monthInt = timeIntervalDateEndDivided?.month
        let dayInt = timeIntervalDateEndDivided?.day
        
        eventDate[DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian), year: yearInt, month: monthInt, day: dayInt)] = .point
        
    }

